# How do I update two variables in a oracle sql server update using case statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to update two variables in a Oracle server as follows:

```
UPDATE UserTable
SET user_email='asdf@company.com', 
               (CASE WHEN reason != '' THEN why_update= 'change email server' END)
WHERE user_id = 123
```

I want to update why_update column only if the user provided a reason for update otherwise leave the column as it is (which is varchar type and can be NULL).

Or any other better solution?

Comment: `case` is an expression, i.e. it evaluates to a value. It cannot perform an action conditionally.

Comment: "oracle sql server"????  'oracle' is an RDBMS product from Oracle Corp.  'SQL Server' is an RDBMS product from Microsoft Corp.  Thus, 'oracle' != 'sql server'.

Comment: Those are **columns** not "variables". And it's a case _expression_ (inside an UPDATE _statement_)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THis will work:

```
UPDATE UserTable
SET user_email='asdf@company.com', 
    why_update= CASE WHEN reason != '' THEN 'change email server' else why_update END
WHERE user_id = 123
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to update multiple columns, you would need to do it like:

```
UPDATE UserTable
SET user_email = 'asdf@company.com', 
    why_update = CASE WHEN reason IS NOT NULL THEN 'change email server' END
WHERE user_id = 123;
```

You would always end up updating both columns - in this case, if `reason` is null, then `why_update` would be set to NULL, losing any previous value. If you don't want that to happen, you would need to add in an `ELSE why_update` clause into the `CASE` expression.

N.B. I have changed your `!= ''` into `IS NOT NULL` because an empty string (`''`) is recognised as being a NULL in Oracle. NULL will never match an `equals` or `not equals` check, so your above `CASE` expression won't work as I suspect you want it to work.